# Looping through hits using painless script

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

Is there a way In Elasticsearch 5.3 to loop through query results using painless script to compute difference between the hits returned by query.

I was trying to loop through the results in a for loop in script and could not what entity to loop on, i was hopping that scripts have something like the update api has ctx.payload.hits.hits that can be used in for loop.

```
"script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "inline": "int total = 0; for (int i = 0; i <  ??? ; i++) { total +=  ???[i]._source['age'].value; } return total;"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same problem and I found this [thred](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/looping-through-hits-using-painless-script/117718) on elastic forums. It looks like using map-reduce is the simplest way to achive "iteration through hits" as I have not found anything else.
As the qquestion on elastic is exactly the same as yours I guess that you have written it, and the follow up question as well.

The question is a bit unclear on what is to the final goal but I do suggestto familiarize you with [MapReduce](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_mapreduce.htm) as it looks like the Scripted metric Aggregation is based upon it. But, reading from the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) it looks like the implementation is quite different as, I quote,:

> Executed **once on the coordinating node after all shards have returned their results**. The script is provided with access to a variable _aggs which is an array of the result of the combine_script on each shard. If a reduce_script is not provided the reduce phase will return the _aggs variable.

So it looks to me as the "reduce job" is performed on one single node after the *map_script* (and the optional *combine_script*) has been performed. This way you could collect all the needed data in a *map_script* and have logic in *reduce_script*.
But I have to emphasize that **I have not a lot experience with those kind of things** and have into some (different) trouble myself.